# Как установить параметр max_connections для БД в .gitlab-ci.yml, которая запускается в докере?

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, gitlab, pipelines

Параметры для тестовой базы указаны в .gitlab-ci.yml. Сейчас необходимо увеличить max_connections и shared_buffers для БД, но поскольку она создается и запускается непонятным мне образом гитлабовским ранером, я не знаю где взять конфиг-файл для бд и через консольную команду при запуске контейнера его тоже передать не могу, т. к. ее видимо запускает сам ранер.

**Помогло в итоге добавление в .gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
services:
  - name: postgres:latest
    command: ["-c", "shared_buffers=256MB", "-c", "max_connections=300"]

variables:
  PG_SYSTEM_SHARED_BUFFERS: 256MB
  POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

Comment: объявленные переменные, судя по всему, используются в Dockerfile.

Comment: Решение правильнее вынести в ответ и отметить этот ответ решением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогло в итоге добавление в .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
services:
  - name: postgres:latest
    command: ["-c", "shared_buffers=256MB", "-c", "max_connections=300"]

variables:
  PG_SYSTEM_SHARED_BUFFERS: 256MB
  POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```